# Where is Jetpack Compose Container?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I read on the Container from some tutorial

- https://joebirch.co/android/exploring-jetpack-compose-container/
- https://levelup.gitconnected.com/jetpack-compose-container-layout-183e655518f2

It is coded as below

```
@Composable
fun Container(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier.None,
    padding: EdgeInsets = EdgeInsets(0.dp),
    alignment: Alignment = Alignment.Center,
    expanded: Boolean = false,
    constraints: DpConstraints = DpConstraints(),
    width: Dp? = null,
    height: Dp? = null,
    children: @Composable() () -> Unit
)
```

Recently while exploring on Jetpack Compose `1.0.0-alpha07`, can no longer see it. Is it no longer supported or what did I miss?

I included all library I could, but it didn't show.

```
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.0.0-alpha07'
    // Tooling support (Previews, etc.)
    implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-tooling:1.0.0-alpha07'
    // Foundation (Border, Background, Box, Image, Scroll, shapes, animations, etc.)
    implementation 'androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:1.0.0-alpha07'
    // Material Design
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.0.0-alpha07'
    // Material design icons
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material-icons-core:1.0.0-alpha07'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:1.0.0-alpha07'
    // Integration with observables
    implementation 'androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:1.0.0-alpha07'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-rxjava2:1.0.0-alpha07'
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**`Container`** has been removed. You can use **`Box`** instead.

androidx.ui: ui - *: Removed in 0.1.0-dev11 version.

[Source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/dec45dc30a6cc8b1d8b344c8038db56020bad9ea)

Comment: `Box` doesn't have the `expanded` parameter though... even though the changelog suggests that it has _more_ parameters, it seems to actually have _fewer_.